# How to center print page on the print preview control?

Tags: c#, winforms, print-preview

How can I adjust the padding(?) of the print page of the print preview?
I tried setting margin like this:

```
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(205, 105, 105, 105);
```

But that doesn't do anything visually!

[image]

I want to adjust the size od the spacing shown with the blue line in this image

Comment: Those margins are where you can/should print. They don't show unless you draw them and the are part of the page. You should see the effect if you ignore them and print outside. The stuff outside the mrgins ought to be cut off.. The grey area is not part of your page!

Comment: I want the preview to look neat, since we use it to show data to user and not necessarily for printing

Comment: You can show the Margins in your PrintPage event  like this:       `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkGray, e.MarginBounds);` and with two FillRectangle calls you can paint a nice gray area..: `e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, e.PageBounds);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.MarginBounds);`

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for...

Comment: Ah, I see. Well it is centered if you don't have the vScrollbar. I doubt you can influence it.